# ¿Como crear un botón de favoritos en un recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo mi recyclerview donde muestro detalles de peliculas, la información es traida con firebase. Quisiera agregar un botón de favoritos, que a pulsar un boton se envie los detalles de la peliculas en otro recyclerview donde se irán guardando. Ya implemente el botón que al pulsar se guarda el detalle de esa pelicula en Sharedpreferences. Funciona todo correcto hasta ahi, pero el problema que tengo es que al traer la información del Sharedpreferences y lo guardo en el recyclerview, solo se guarda una unica pelicula, y al querer guardar otra reemplaza al que esta ya guardada.
Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria.

ESTE ES EL DETALLE DE LAS PELICULAS DONDE ESTA EL BOTON FAVORITO

```
public class detalle_pelicula extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView titulo, titulo_original, tamano_descarga, idioma, genero, duracion, ano, sinopsis, pais, 
 fecha_estreno;
ImageView imageView, button, buttonComp;
CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalle_pelicula);

    //con este codigo pongo el icono en el actionbar
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.icono);

    //quito el titulo del actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setElevation(300);

    imagenPrincipal();

    //en esta funcion se encuentra toda la informacion extra traida del recyclerview de cada pelicula
    DetallePelicula();

    BotonDescarga();

    BotonCompartir();

    final String titul = getIntent().getStringExtra("titulo");
    final String anio =  getIntent().getStringExtra("año");
    final String imagen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("imagen");
    final String fecha =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fecha_estreno");

    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.favorito2);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("favorito", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(detalle_pelicula.this, "Se ha añadido a favoritos", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                editor.putString("titulo",titul);
                editor.putString("anio",anio);
                editor.putString("imagen",imagen);
                editor.putString("fecha",fecha);
                editor.apply();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(detalle_pelicula.this, "Se ha eliminado de favoritos", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editorr = 
     detalle_pelicula.this.getSharedPreferences("favorito", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editorr.remove("titulo");
                editorr.remove("anio");
                editorr.remove("fecha");
                editorr.remove("imagen");
                editorr.apply();
            }}});


}
```

ACA TRAIGO LA INFORMACIÓN Y LO GUARDO EN EL RECYCLERVIEW

```
public class Favorito extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
adapterFavorito adapter;
ArrayList<Peliculas_favoritos> listaPeliculas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorito);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.favorito_recy);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
 false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    listaPeliculas = new ArrayList<>();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("favorito", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String titul = prefs.getString("titulo",null );
    String anio = prefs.getString("anio",null);
    String fecha = prefs.getString("fecha",null);
    String imagen = prefs.getString("imagen",null );

    listaPeliculas.add(new Peliculas_favoritos(titul,imagen,anio,fecha));

    adapter = new adapterFavorito(this, listaPeliculas);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: Para guardar una lista de películas en SharedPreferences debes stringificar tu lista, es decir, convertir la lista en un string.  Para ésto puedes usar la librería Gson.  La lógica para guardar es 1. Deserializar el string a tu lista de películas, 2. Guardar la nueva favorita en la lista y 3. Convertir la lista a string para guardar.  Y lo mismo para borrar, donde sólo necesitas la id.

Comment: Hola ante todo gracias por la ayuda, yo intente hacerlo con un Gson, guardaba la lista del recyclerview en ella, pero al momento de traer los datos y guardarla en el recyclerview de la actividad de los favoritos, me mostraba toda la lista completa en vez de mostrarme solo una. Es decir al presionar el boton de favorito de una sola pelicula, me guardaba todas las peliculas de ese recylerview.

Comment: Tal vez lo estaba implementando mal, si me lo puede mostrar en codigo se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Tengo un proyecto en bitbucket antigüo pero del que se pueden coger ideas, está en Kotlin, pero lo entenderás.  Es un datasource de favoritos con shared preferences https://bitbucket.org/ManuelMato/baseproject/src/develop/app/src/main/java/com/example/manuel/baseproject/data/datasource/local/FavoritesLocalDataSource.kt

Comment: Usa sqllite , o lo nuevo de android Room. O usa firebase en la nube.